# Free shipping code is not working for UPS for magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using a CART PRICE RULE for creating a coupon code that will when applied than all shipping amount turn to zero.

Problem is it is worked for all shipping method except UPS.

Please if someone guide what is i am making mistake for UPS configuration.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Confirm you have the UPS shipping method marked to use with Free Shipping.**

Go to `Stores>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods>UPS` **update the "Free Method" field**. Then save, reindex if needed, and flush cache.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This free method showing all the time. i want if someone when applied a coupon code than amount will turn to zero. Like any other shipping method did.